# LNK 1104 error to lib file - Continues despite removing includes and links

Tags: c++, linker-errors

A link error to a lib file popped up out of the blue in a c++ application of mine after code was working fine in my last session.

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file '..........\Program Files
>   (x86)\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API
>   Windows\api\lib\fmodex_vc.lib'

I triple checked my project directories were set up correctly to link to the lib file, that the file existed in said directory and that it was a working version of the .lib.

My next step was to remove the includes to the file and the links to bypass the error and work on the rest of my code until the problem was solved. The error remains, however, despite:

- Commenting out absolutely every include relating to the lib.
- Commenting out absolutely every line of code dependant on the includes.
- Removing the directory from VC++ Directories in the project properties.
- Checking the Additional Library Directories field was also clear of references.

To my understanding this should have made the library and related code virtually non-existant to the compiler.

What am I missing?

The library itself is fmodex_vc.lib - part of the FMOD API for providing sound to interactive applications.

Again, the application was working one session, but failed to compile the next. I hadn't touched the code since so this led me to believe some aspect of VS is at fault. I'd like to avoid the time involded in re-installing if possible as I'm on the clock for a review tomorrow evening and there are a few more things I'd like to smooth out before then. If necessary, however, I won't hesitate.

Very much appreciate the help.

Comment: What version of VS are you using? Have you tried running `Build -> Clean Solution`? Any reason you can't just try making a fresh solution, and see if that links?

Comment: Does the fmodex_vc.lib really exists? Has it a size different from zero (accidentally cleared)? Is the file probably opened by a different process (sharing violation)?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! 

VS 2010 is the version I'm running. I've cleaned the solution and re-built with every fix attempt. It's a big solution, but I'll create a new one and add h's and cpp's one by one to see to see where the error pops up again. 

Yes, the file exists. Tried was swapping the lib with a verified correct copy. Re-started my pc several times since so I don't think a sharing violation could be occuring. 

The baffling thing is the error continuing despite taking the steps above to ensure no includes to the lib remain and that no links and directory references exist.